# setting up Google Webpage Optimizer where text and conversion pages are the same

Tags: google-website-optimizer

I have a site where both landing and thank you page are index.php page with different content loaded dynamically.  As I'm generating the javascript and trying to validate it, it gives me an error saying that JS is not installed on the thank you page, which makes sense, because its content is not loaded yet.  I was wondering how I can circumvent this issue?  Any suggestions?

Thanks!
Luka

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do the offline validation of the conversion page, [follow these instructions](http://www.google.com/support/websiteoptimizer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=69247).